# How to index query List with Linq?

Tags: c#, performance, list, linq

I have a List of DTO's with 8 fields, the List have 477.000 records loaded fron a XML file, when I filtered items on this list the CPU consumed 25% in one core, I think this behavior is because the List is not indexed, is it posible index that list?

DTO

```
public class PriceDto
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string Max { get; set; }
    public string Min { get; set; }
    public string PorcentValue { get; set; }
    public string PromotionPrice { get; set; }
    public string ConditionClass { get; set; }
    public string Vat { get; set; }
}
```

Linq Query

```
Price = AllPrices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Filter == FilterId.ConsecutiveFilter.Trim() &&
x.ConditionClass == accessSequenceItem.PriceCondition &&
x.Material == CodeMaterial);
```

Comment: It had a task, but doing tests I deleted the code, on this moment I have in one core, so it consume 25%, the real question is if there are some way to create indexed lists to filter with Linq

Comment: Are you always filtering on the same fields? If its always the same fields it makes it easier to create an index. Are you running multiple filters against the same dataset or only ever one query against the dataset? If you only ever run one query against a dataset then creating the index will likely be no faster than just running the query. Also to be sure do you get the same behaviour of slowness if you don't attempt to parallelize it? Just wanting to confirm that its not a problem with your parallelization (since currently your query just seems to be a `FirstOrDefault` call).

Comment: @Chris, yes the filter is on same fields, the parallelism is because I need to do 2.000+ querys to find distinct prices when I load a Excel file.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I created the Dictionary and I achieved differences in 20,000% better with dictionary (10.000 ticks vs 220'000.000 ticks), but I have the doubt if Linq natively have that, because I need create another lists

Comment: Maybe a library or something else? I can search with Linq over the keys of the Dictionary?

Comment: `but I have the doubt if Linq natively have that` No, it doesn't have that out of the box. You will need to build that yourself.

Comment: Could you use indexed overload for `Select`? `var nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select((index, num) => new { index, num });`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Lookup` or a `Dictionary<Lookup>` or even a `Dictionary<Dictionary<Lookup>>` with LINQ and then use that for your queries. This trades space for time, but the improvement will really depend on the distribution of values in the different fields. With 500,000 in a random sample data set of 100 filters, 100 materials and 25 conditions, indexing on filter and material produces the fastest result for 2000 random queries, about 33 times faster than the plain query. 2000 queries for non-existent data was from 60 to 800 times faster with the lookup.

Here is the code to create the double index structure:

```
var filterMaterialMap = AllPrices.GroupBy(ap => ap.Filter).ToDictionary(apfg => apfg.Key, apfg => apfg.ToLookup(ap => ap.Material));
```

You run a query like so:

```
PriceDto Price = null;
if (filterMaterialMap.TryGetValue(FilterId.ConsecutiveFilter.Trim(), out var matDict))
    Price = matDict[CodeMaterial].FirstOrDefault(ap => ap.ConditionClass == accessSequenceItem.PriceCondition);
```

The other cases are a single field index:

```
var filterMap = AllPrices.ToLookup(ap => ap.Filter);
var Price = filterMap[FilterId.ConsecutiveFilter.Trim()].FirstOrDefault(ap => ap.Material == CodeMaterial && ap.ConditionClass == accessSequenceItem.PriceCondition);
```

and all three fields indexed:

```
var filterMaterialConditionMap = AllPrices.GroupBy(ap => ap.Filter)
                                          .ToDictionary(apfg => apfg.Key, apfg => apfg.GroupBy(ap => ap.Material)
                                                                                      .ToDictionary(apfmg => apfmg.Key, apfmg => apfmg.ToLookup(ap => ap.ConditionClass)));
PriceDto Price = null;
if (filterMaterialConditionMap.TryGetValue(FilterId.ConsecutiveFilter.Trim(), out var matDict))
    if (matDict.TryGetValue(CodeMaterial, out var condDict))
        Price = condDict[accessSequenceItem.PriceCondition].FirstOrDefault();
```